# Moving cursor to end of line when using history-search-backward

Tags: bash, readline

I recently added the following lines to my `.inputrc`:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

However, I noticed when using this that my cursor does not jump to the end of the line. For example, if I type `ls` then hit up, my terminal will look like this (`|` being the cursors):

```
ls |verylongdir
```

What I want is:

```
ls verylongdir|
```

I believe zsh behaves this way with the same command. Is there any way to do this in bash?

Comment: zsh does not behave that way by default. The bash-style is represented by `history-beginning-search-backward`. I had to load `history-search-end` and define and use its `history-beginning-search-backward-end` widget instead.

Comment: @wrlee This is helpful. For the zsh newbies among us, the 2 statements I required were (each on a separate line): `autoload -U history-search-end`; `bindkey '^[[A' history-beginning-search-backward-end`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and managed to find the solution with some experimentation.

I added the following to my `.inputrc`

```
"\eOA": history-search-backward # Up
"\eOB": history-search-forward  # Down
"\C-P": "\eOA\C-E"              # Ctrl-P
"\C-N": "\eOB\C-E"              # Ctrl-N
```

This binds two hotkeys to Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N. One for history search, and the other Ctrl-E for `end-of-line`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question